# How to import external files inside the selector with Dart Sass

Tags: css, sass, dart-sass

I want to import external files inside the selector using Dart Sass.
When I use @use to realize this, it causes an error.

```
//error
.selector {
    @use 'external-file';
}
```

I used to use @import to do this before with node-sass and it was OK.

```
.selector {
    @import 'external-file';
}
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing with Dart Sass and want to know how.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching the same thing and finally found the solution.
`meta.load-css` does the trick.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#load-css

```
@use "sass:meta";
.selector {
    @include meta.load-css('external-file');
}
```